# Angular: Pass service as an argument

Tags: angular, typescript, service

I want to put some functions in an external file and call them from different components and make the code cleaner.

The thing is, these functions use a service:

**MyFunctions class**

```js
import { Service1 } from "../_services";
export class MyFunctions {
  constructor(private service: Service1) {}
  bookingFunctions = {
    confirm: (id: any) => {
      this.service.confirmTrip(id);
    }
  };
}
```

**My component**

```js
import MyFunctions from "../../../functions";
...
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private service: Service1
    ) {}
...
    myFunctions = new MyFunctions(this.service);
... 
    confirmBooking(id: number){
      this.myFunctions.bookingFunctions.confirmBooking(id);
    }
... 
}
```

My question: This is working fine, but I've never seen such a solution during my searches. What could be wrong with this solution?

Can I pass the service instance `Service1` to the constructor of `MyFunctions` class?

I'm like *it works! why?!*

Comment: It works because of [Dependency Injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection).

Answer (score 1):

Probably, your service of type 'Service1', has this inside:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
```

so, the instance of the service is the same for the whole app :
the service, is like a **singleton** (like a class globaly instanciated for all the app).

If you don't put providedIn: 'root', and inject the service into the PROVIDERS:[] section of a module, the service only will work in that module.

On the other hand, if you specify the service inside the component itself, like this:

```
// Component A

@Component({
/* . . . */
  providers: [MyService]
})
```

the service only will be accesible to this components and its descendants, not to other components.
And, if another component take the same service by the same way:

```
// Component B

@Component({
/* . . . */
  providers: [MyService]
})
```

both components **WILL NOT SHARE the same service**, the services intances will be different.

Comment: Thanks, indeed, that's what I've done.
What I was wondering about really is how can passing the instance of the service (this.service) to the constructor of the other class makes the service work there. So, it's because of the DI, right?